# What is the best way to attach a timber block to IKEA Linnmon desktop?

Tags: wood

I want to fix a metal wire cable tray to an Ikea Linnmon desktop with screws, however the desktop has honeycomb filling therefore it is not suitable for screws. I think maybe attaching a timber block to the desktop then fixing the tray to the block will be a solution. What is the best way to do that? I am thinking of glue, but which type of glue? The material of the desktop is Fibreboard, Acrylic paint, according to Ikea website. The timber block I plan to use would be untreated (I guess?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Couple questions: how thick is the desktop? And approximately where are you? (US products aren't always available in Europe, and so on.)

Comment: And is the tray carrying any weight other than cables? (Heavy transformer, etc...?)

Comment: Attach to the frame supporting the desktop.

Comment: If you’re gluing a block of wood to the desk, why not skip the block and just glue the tray itself? There are also some surprisingly strong double-sided tapes (3M VHB, for example) that would probably work for you.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The desktop is about 5cm thick. I am based in UK. The tray would carry some chargers and extensions with cable. It won't be too heavy I think. Thanks!

Comment: @spuck It is a metal wire tray, I thought maybe fixing it to a block using screws would be stronger.

Comment: Would suggest something like this: https://johnsmithaberdeen.co.uk/products/copy-of-6x3-4-self-tapping-screw-bzp-pan-head-pack-of-50 (or any relatively fat screw with coarse threads). Predrill smaller than the root size and put a lot of pressure on while screwing so the threads cut cleanly in.

Answer (score 1):

you probably don't need the timber block, just Use "Molly"s  (hollow wall anchors) or banana-peel rivets.